# What is a 'CONJUGATE KEY' in a DBMS

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is a 'CONJUGATE KEY' in a DBMS.

Comment: I did a search on google couldn't find anything relevant. First is there a key called `CONJUGATE KEY` in dbms ?

Comment: Mybe you mean a composite key , I never heard about `CONJUGATE KEY` , all what I know is : `Primary Key  , Super Key , Candidate Key , Alternate Key  , Composite Key  , Foreign Key `

Comment: That is what I want to know :) @Prdp

Comment: The dictionary defines `conjugate` as `The definition of conjugate is two or more things joined together.` So with this definition we can say that this could mean a composite key.

Comment: @WEI_DBA . . . Actually, from that definition, I would interpret "foreign key".  But I wouldn't be surprised if it meant something like "candidate primary key".

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Good point!

Comment: No!, I know what a composite key is :) @Sami

Comment: Ok , so you are asking about `Foreign Key ` as @GordonLinoff say.

Comment: In what context did you come across conjugate key? Is it a text book or article? Depending on the source it could be a translation issue.

Comment: In an interview :( I have also never heard anything like 'conjugate key'.

Comment: I think I might use this interview technique in the future -- ask about a technical word that does not exist just to see what the candidate will do.

Comment: It is a kind of a term that sounds like 'it may exist' but now I am confirm that it does not @Hogan

Comment: It might be related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) from boolean logic, but I also must admit I've never heard of `CONJUGATE` key. Could the question be "What does it mean to conjugate the key in a DBMS"?

Comment: Wise candidates are wary of interviewers who use made-up but real-sounding jargon. It could mean the workplace they represent has become so detached from the state of the art that they collectively don't know what they don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Actually , I never heard about `CONJUGATE KEY` in DBMS .

**keys in DBMS:**

- **Primary Key:** A primary is a column or set of columns in a table that uniquely identifies tuples (rows) in that table.
- **Super Key:** A super key is a set of one of more columns (attributes) to uniquely identify rows in a table.
- **Candidate Key:** A super key with no redundant attribute is known as candidate key
- **Alternate Key:** Out of all candidate keys, only one gets selected as primary key, remaining keys are known as alternate or secondary keys.
- **Composite Key:** A key that consists of more than one attribute to uniquely identify rows (also known as records & tuples) in a table is called composite key.
- **Foreign Key :** Foreign keys are the columns of a table that points to the primary key of another table. They act as a cross-reference between tables.